# Prevent IPython/PyLab from accidentally using too much memory

Tags: python, linux, numpy, ipython

When using numpy in PyLab I often forget that for example a `1000x1000x1000`-array will take up 8GB of memory. It has often happened to me that I create such an array and my computer becomes incredibly slow because it is paging >2GB of memory (I'm on Linux btw). This in turn makes it difficult to kill the PyLab process.

So my question is if there is a way to limit IPython's memory usage to prevent this kind of situation.